# Jquery TypeError: a is undefined when trying to dynamically create table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im new to Jquery and have been trying to get some code working for dynamically creating a table. In doing so i have come up with an issue.
I have a web service that will respond in JSON the data looks like this (sample)

```
{
        "aaData": [
            1
        ],
        "aaSorting": [
            1,
            "desc"
        ],
        "aoColumns": {
            "sTitle": "Title1"
        }
   }
```

The entire java script is bellow
        `

```
        $(document).ready
        (
            function() 
            {
                $.getJSON
                (
                    'http://intranet/testing/data/public.php', function(data) 
                    {
                        var newTable = '<thead><tr>'; 
                        $.each
                        (
                            data[0], function(key, value) 
                            {
                                newTable += "<th>" + key + "</th>";
                            }
                        );
                        newTable += "</tr></thead><tbody>";                  
                        $.each
                        (
                            data, function(key, row) 
                            {
                                newTable += "<tr>";
                                $.each
                                (
                                    row, function(key, fieldValue) 
                                    {
                                       newTable += "<td>" + fieldValue + "</td>";
                                    }
                                );
                                newTable += "</tr>";
                            }
                        );
                        newTable += '<tbody>';
                       $('#example').html(newTable);  
                    }
                );
                $('#example').dataTable(); 
            }
        );
    </script>`
```

Would appreciate some help in fixing this.

Comment: Not sure what your data looks like or if you have access to change it, but DataTables does take JSON from an AJAX call to populate a table. See the docs:

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: I have tried thatexample. i cant work out how to use the data to populate the html table by appending to the dom document before i do the dataTable().